# option not being selected by default unless it's value is null vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a select with multiple options. What I'm trying to achieve is to have one option which is selected by default and disabled so you can't click it again (I want it to work similar to a placeholder).

The problem is that the *disabled* and *selected* tags don't work unless the *value* is null.

I already have an option with the value null (the 2nd option), which means that when I try to press it, it automatically selects the disabled option.

This is my code:

```
<label>Selectează specialitatea</label>
<select v-model="modalIU.inpIdSpecialitate">
     <option :value="null" disabled selected class="uk-text-muted">Selectează specialitatea</option>
     <option :value='null'>Fără legătură specialitate</option>
     <option v-for="item in allSectiiSpecialitati.filter(el => el.idSpecialitate !== null).sort((a, b) => (a.denumireSpecialitate > b.denumireSpecialitate) ? 1 : -1)">@{{ item.denumireSpecialitate }}</option>
</select>
```

And this what i'm trying to achieve with the first option being selected by default, but disabled so you can't select it again.

[image: picture]

Comment: Can you try set the default option to `<option selected disabled value="">...</option>`? Empty value instead of `null`, or just put the empty value on the second one if the first one needs to be null

Comment: @NicolaSpadari if i make the value of the first option empty, the selected tag doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @NicolaSpadari messed around a bit more and your solution worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of giving both of my option the value *null*, I give null to the disabled option and the other selectable option is "".